# What is the max resolution output by the HDMI port of the MacBook Pro Early 2011

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, resolution, displayport

The MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) has a Thunderbolt port of which I would like to know the maximum resolution. It does not say what it is on the [specs site](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp619?locale=en_US) specifically. It merely says "supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors", without specifying whether this holds true for all types of connections including HDMI. I have tested a miniDP to HDMI adapter that allegedly supports HDMI up to 4096x2160, but the max resolution i get is 2048x1152. I don't know if this is due to the Thunderbolt port or the adapter.

Comment: What is the actual display capable of, what is it's max resolution?

Comment: the cable is fine. I tried it with a different computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to EveryMac.com, there were two 13-inch, Early 2011 MacBook Pro models—the [2.3 GHz i5](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html) and the [2.7 GHz i7](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.7-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html). It actually doesn't matter which you have. They both have a Intel HD Graphics 3000, which does indeed support an 2560 by 1600 external display. It's your adapter.